# How to populate a map

Tags: loops, dictionary, go

How can I populate this map on Golang?
I try two for, but not add news key. I want to create a matrix mult, some help is welcome. My code ([Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xVOVKJD0f2p)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    ProgPorLetra := map[string]map[string]string{
        "Seg": {},
        "Ter": {},
        "Qua": {},
        "Qui": {},
        "Sex": {},
        "Sab": {},
        "Dom": {},
    }
    i := 0
    for i < 6 {
        switch i {
        case 1:
            ProgPorLetra["Seg"]["Valor"] = "Segunda"
        case 2:
            ProgPorLetra["Ter"]["Valor"] = "Terça"
        case 3:
            ProgPorLetra["Qua"]["Valor"] = "Quarta"
        case 4:
            ProgPorLetra["Qui"]["Valor"] = "Quinta"
        case 5:
            ProgPorLetra["Sex"]["Valor"] = "Sexta"
        case 6:
            ProgPorLetra["Sab"]["Valor"] = "Sabado"
        case 0:
            ProgPorLetra["Dom"]["Valor"] = "Domingo"
        }
        i++
    }
    fmt.Println(ProgPorLetra)
}
```

Comment: What is not expected in this output: https://play.golang.org/ ?

Comment: @zerkms I think you mean https://play.golang.org/p/xVOVKJD0f2p

Comment: @davi-sousa You should provide some more information as what the expected result is. Or what you want to optimize. That is not exactly clear

Comment: @Sascha oops, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, if you change `for i < 6` to `for i < 7`, it should work fine.

But you don't need to loop for this. You can use one of the following:

https://play.golang.org/p/M8-HJR7sFLW

https://play.golang.org/p/zWUyeGuIDf5